# How can we add multiple ac_configure_args for multiple AC_CONFIG_SUBDIRS in configure.ac for autoconf?

Tags: autotools, configure, autoconf

I have main working directory with multiple other sub-directories (different libraries with their own autotools). Main configure.ac contains AC_CONFIG_SUBDIRS(dir1, dir2) macro to include those sub-directories, and configure arguments are added using 'ac_configure_args="--with-openssl ..."'  'export ac_configure_args'. But 'ac_configure_args' will be applied to both the directories i.e. dir1 and dir2. Is there any way that we can apply different configure args for different sub-directories?

Comment: `AX_SUBDIRS_CONFIGURE` might be option. https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/ax_subdirs_configure.html

Answer (score 0):

No, there does not seem to be. In any case, configure arguments are best left up to whoever is building the software.